# What else limits readyboost space?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, readyboost, exfat

I’m trying to use about 5GB a 64GB usb flash drive—already formatted as exFAT—for ReadyBoost on a 64bit Windows 7 machine, but the slider for space to reserve ends at 4094MB.

After 2 hours of Googling I haven’t found anything other than os or file system that would limit ReadyBoost to 4 gigs, but it’s not either of those.

What am I missing?

Comment: To my knowledge, 4 GB is the general limit on ReadyBoost. I think I remember having this difficulty before. Nevertheless, you may want to question your use of ReadyBoost. ReadyBoost is designed for computers with very little RAM (I think I had heard <1.5 GB was usually where it had the biggest effect) , and this may explain why the 4 GB limit is imposed. It is unlikely that anyone starting out with such a small amount of RAM would want to suddenly expand their memory so significantly. That being said, I don't know if 4 GB is a physical limitation.

Comment: @fakedad: According to what I've read so far, 64bit versions of windows 7  and later are supposed to raise the 4GB limit to 32GB per device as long as the file system supports larger files.

Comment: @fakedad This machine has 5GB of RAM, which is very little for how it's used; it's currently 10GB deep in pagefile. I know the real solution would be to get more ram, but i'm trying to be cheap and see what i can do with what i already have.

Comment: There is a limit to the total system memory you can have if you want to use ReadyBoost.  Why are you using exFAT that likely is the reason.

Comment: I would agree. NTFS is probably a better choice for a file system.

Comment: How the computer is used is really irrelevant. The usefulness is limited by the speed of USB. From helpdeskgeek.com, "ReadyBoost will not make a significant difference if you have 4GB or more of RAM already installed." While there will likely be some increase in performance, ReadyBoost probably won't help you much if you already have 5 GB of RAM. After doing some research, I found that ReadyBoost's limit was upped to significantly in Windows 7. I haven't used ReadyBoost since I had Vista, so I was under the impression that 4 GB was still the limit.

Comment: As others have said, switching to NTFS will most likely resolve the issue. According to Microsoft TechNet, FAT32 carries the 4 GB limitation. Presumably exFAT does as well.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm using exFAT because that's what it was by default, and I don't want to reformat if i don't have to since I'm already using part of it(before anyone asks, there is still a lot more space left than it's letting me use). exFAT isn't supposed to have the 4GB limit.

Comment: Windows also hates flash drives that are partitioned

Comment: I reformatted to NTFS and now it's letting me use 32GB, but i still don't understand why exFAT raises the limit for some people but not for others on the same version of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use NTFS. When using exFat my computer only recognized 4Gb of a 32 Gb SD card. Format your SD card using the NTFS (I did a full format, not quick format). Windows will recognize the real amount of your SD card.